# How to have AS alias in CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Here some simple test-tables with test-data.

```
CREATE DATABASE mytest;
USE mytest;

CREATE TABLE person (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR (10));
CREATE TABLE male (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, person_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE female (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, person_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (1, "Sam");
INSERT INTO male (person_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (2, "Jim");
INSERT INTO male (person_id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (3, "Sue");
INSERT INTO female (person_id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (4, "Ida");
INSERT INTO female (person_id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (5, "Robo");
```

Have a look.

```
MariaDB [mytest]> SELECT * FROM person;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | Sam  |
|    2 | Jim  |
|    3 | Sue  |
|    4 | Ida  |
|    5 | Robo |
+------+------+


MariaDB [mytest]> SELECT * FROM male;
+----+-----------+
| id | person_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
+----+-----------+

MariaDB [mytest]> SELECT * FROM female;
+----+-----------+
| id | person_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         3 |
|  2 |         4 |
+----+-----------+
```

Lets select every person with a column for the gender.

```
MariaDB [mytest]> SELECT name, CASE  
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
  ELSE 'X' END AS gender 
FROM person;
+------+--------+
| name | gender |
+------+--------+
| Sam  | M      |
| Jim  | M      |
| Sue  | F      |
| Ida  | F      |
| Robo | X      |
+------+--------+
```

Thats fine. But now I like to filter regarding the gender.

```
SELECT name, CASE  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
      ELSE 'X' END AS gender 
    FROM person WHERE gender = 'X';
```

Thats not working anymore.

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gender' in 'where clause'

Whats the problem here? I did the alias with AS. It is working with Sqlite but not with MariaDB.

Comment: Write valid ANSI/ISO SQL standard code, using a alias in a WHERE clause from a SELECT on the same "level" is simply not allowed..

Comment: Use your query as a subquery and apply to it the condition.

Comment: If you don't want to have to type out all of that `CASE` statement again (or you're not confident in the query optimiser) then use a sub-query, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT name, CASE etc.. END AS gender FROM person) a WHERE a.gender = 'X';`

Comment: Also this schema feels to "over normalized" whats the point of the separated male and female tables?   i could agree with a normalized `gender` table and a `gender_id` in the main table..

Comment: Use only one table, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (as with most databases) does not allow aliases in the `WHERE`.  However, it does allow aliases in the `HAVING` clause and it extends the use of `HAVING` to non-aggregation queries.

So, you can write:

```
SELECT name, CASE  
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
             ELSE 'X'
        END) AS gender 
FROM person
HAVING gender = 'X';
```

At least one reason for this is because (historically always) MySQL stores derived tables (subqueries in the `FROM` clause) in temporary tables -- this adds overhead to queries.  Requiring a subquery to filter on a computed column is expensive; the `HAVING` extension is a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to an alias from the SELECT clause in your WHERE clause, but you can use a subquery or CTE:

```
-- Subquery
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT name, CASE  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
      ELSE 'X' END AS gender 
  FROM person 
) as subqry
WHERE gender = 'X';

-- CTE
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name, CASE  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
      ELSE 'X' END AS gender 
  FROM person 
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE gender = 'X';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change things around a bit you can get the same results

```
SELECT name, CASE  
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id) THEN 'M'  
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id) THEN 'F'  
  ELSE 'X' END AS gender 
FROM person WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM male WHERE male.person_id = person.id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM female WHERE female.person_id = person.id)
```